# Do we need to maintain the app/code/Magento/ in git after 2.4.6-p1 upgrade

Tags: magento2, git, magento2.4.6

There is one ****untracked folder `app/code/Magento/`** from git** after upgrading the Magento site to the latest version of 2.4.6-p1.
**Do we need to maintain this in git?**

Comment: You can ignore or delete from local. This folder only having test case files.Recently We also updated and seeing this folder.

Comment: Yes, Thanks Let me remove it